# Using Selenium Java get special characters (Chinese, Japanese) but gives?

Tags: java, string, selenium, special-characters

I have a requirement where I would like to read combination of English and non English characters from a dropdown on Web UI
Example- abcd , efgh, 你好, こんにちは

```
public void test(){
    dropdown.click();
    Select newValues = new Select(dropdown);
    List<WebElement> listNewValues  = countryValues.getOptions();
    ArrayList<String> actualDropDownItems = new ArrayList();
    for(WebElement value : listNewValues){
        actualDropDownItems.add(value.getText());
        System.out.println(value.getText().toString());
        }
```

If I try to run and print this, I get ?? for Chinese and Japanese values.
Please note I have read some of the previous suggestions and in eclipse at project> properties level> Resource> Other is set to UTF-8.
Everywhere it is suggested to use UTF-8. But what else can I do If I have already set this at project properties level.

Is there any other easier way of getting this non-English characters? Any help is appreciated.

P.S. I had also tried using BufferedWriter approach, but it gives me ­å›½æ—¥æœ¬ëŒ€í•œë¯¼êµ­ instead of 你好, こんにちは

Comment: Where are you seeing “??” characters?  Is it in a Windows command window?  Does the drop-down itself appear to contain the correct characters in the browser?

Comment: Please update your question by URL or page source code to be able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @VGR It is web UI. The drop-down certainly has correct characters and I see them properly in browser when inspecting elements.

Comment: I repeat:  Where you are seeing “??” characters?  How are you viewing the output of System.out.println?

Comment: @VGR sorry I didn't follow you earlier. I'm seeing ?? on eclipse console. To clarify if I run following command I get ?? System.out.println(value.getText().toString());

And if I run something like below, I get å›½æ—¥æœ¬ëŒ€í•œë¯¼êµ­
    OutputStream outputStream = System.out;
    OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8");
      BufferedWriter output_BufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(outputStreamWriter);
            output_BufferedWriter.write(value.getText().toString());
            output_BufferedWriter.flush();

Answer (score 0):

Running simple System.out.println("你好"); was not giving me correct output on Eclipse console.
Looks like setting eclipse at project level was not doing anything to help me.
project> properties level> Resource> Other is set to UTF-8

Did right click on test, Coverage As> Coverage configuration > Common and then set Other to UTF-8, solved my problem.